# Thunderbird - Filter by folder

Tags: thunderbird

I want to filter messages from a specific IMAP *folder* to be moved to Local Folders.

Message Filters seems only able to filter by headers/size/attachments/status, not folder.

Is there a way to automatically move **all messages delivered to a specific folder (regardless of headers/attachments/content)** into Local Folders?

Answer (score 1):

The [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) Add-On offers that functionality.

Comment: FiltaQuilla adds a filter for "IF FOLDER NAME IS" so that you can be specific and pick a particular IMAP folder, and only move emails in that one folder. This solved an issue where my SERVER decides to put certain emails in the spam folder, so now I can move the IMAP SPAM to my Local Junk folder and I can move the IMAP INBOX to my Local Inbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [Filter Subfolders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filter-subfolders/) will give you what you want.  How are the emails getting into the IMAP folder in the first place - via a gmail rule?

Comment: Is it under your control, if so, you could add a X- message header to the email as it gets sorted, and then use the in-built filters.

Comment: The Add-On is not supported by current versions of Thunderbird anymore.

Comment: This add-on (Filter Subfolders) is no longer supported on current versions of Thunderbird. See the other answer by @Twilite in this thread about using the FiltaQuilla add-on.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some header in the message that identifies the account and/or server.

If you do not see that header in the filter creation, you could maybe use `mailnews.customHeaders` in [Thunderbird settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Modify_Thunderbird_settings) as described [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mail_and_news_settings) :

> String : List of custom headers. Except for the last entry each ends with ':' and the list is seperated using spaces. For example:
>   X-Spam-hits: Body: Reply-To